# DynamoDB - Get all rows where primary key is in a range

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

My table has following schema:

Hash Key: ProxyID
Range Key: Timestamp

Being from a MySQL background, I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Timestamp < now() - 10 minutes
```

Basically, I want to fetch last few records of every proxy. Right now I am using this:

```
$client->query(array(
        'TableName' => 'server_logs',
        'AttributesToGet' => array('Proxy ID', 'Timestamp', 'usageCPUTotalPercent', 'numberOfUsers', 'usageMemoryTotalPercent'),
        'KeyConditions' => array(
            'Proxy ID' => array(
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'EQ',
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('N' => (String)$proxyId)
                )
            ),
            'Timestamp' => array(
                'ComparisonOperator' => 'BETWEEN',
                'AttributeValueList' => array(
                    array('N' => (String)$fromTime),
                    array('N' => (String)$toTime)
                )
            )
        ),
    ));
```

But I have to run this query for EVERY proxy server and there are 100s of them. Is there any way I can get this done in a single query?

Comment: you can use `IN` instead of `EQ` for example

Comment: `IN` comparison operator is not available for Query

Comment: then use scan instead of query

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are not going to find the right solution in dynamodb api as it is not suited for this type of problems.

What you basically want is to do a range query without a hash - breaking the concept of evenly distributed hashing of elements that DynamoDB requires in order to supply the consistent and predictable performance.

My advice is to look outside of DynamoDB if that's the question you need answered. If the data is not too big - I suggest you stick with MySQL for this case

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this with a single query, but depending on the number of individual timestamps between `now()` and `-10 minutes`, it may be more efficient to use a [Global Secondary Index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the table.

For example:

```
Index name: ProxiesByTime
Hash key: Timestamp
Range key: ProxyID
```

You only have to query for the timestamps that you need and you'll get back all proxy server IDs that share that timestamp.

I'm honestly not convinced that this is a good approach for you, but something for you to think about. I have a similar scenario with a much simpler requirement to track the latest records created by day. It's easy for me to store each day as an Integer and have a Global Secondary Index to query for all records by each day.

Comment: problem is, there can be 10 x 60 x 1000 possible timestamps between `now()` and `-10 minutes` because every node pushes data independently

Comment: Yup, bad idea then! :)